# Cumulative percentage for each period using Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I wanted to have the cumulative percent of hours for every 4 weeks of a year and and display it in a visual matrix together .

I tried to add this calculated column in the matrix :

```
Cumule=Calculate (SUM(My_Table[Hours]))
```

and it just gives the total for each week independently and without restarting in the 4th week for exemple .

this is the result that i'm looking for :

| PLI | week 1 | week2 | week3 | week4 | week5 | week6 | week7 | week8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PLI1 | 15% | 25% | 34% | **42%** | 11.3% | 17% | 25% | **30%** |
| PLI2 | 23% | 30% | 33% | **39.56%** | 10% | 13% | 20% | **27%** |
| PLI3 | 36% | 40.1% | 44.35% | **50%** | 15% | 20% | 23% | **39.9%** |

PLI1[week2]=PLI1[week1]+5%
PLI1[week3]=PLI1[week2]+9%

PLI1[week4]=PLI1[week3]+8%

etc ..

I apologize if I missed the solution  and would please you to provide me the link to the solution /the solution in the comments.

here is my Table :

[image: table projet]

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR YOUR HELP .

Comment: how do you get names for columns `week 1; week2` is it a name of measure or you have a date table with weeks?  `PLI1[week1]+5%` 5% of which value?

Comment: I have a table that contains a date column , columns for week,year, month of this date, and other numeric columns and ID

Comment: Ok, then what about my second question`PLI1[week1]+5% 5% of which value?` How do you source 5%?

Comment: 5% is a calculated column from another table , PLI1[week1]+5%  was an exemple .

Comment: Please add a names of `columns for week` and value format (sample value) in there, and a name for a calculated column like `tableName[columnName]`. Please note, that in a matrix it's a measure and in the table it's a calculated column, so we will have the same understanding for your data model.

Comment: `in matrix it's a measure ` i mean if you calculate something in matrix

Comment: Sorry if i've missed some details , i'm  still a beginner in dax , so the vaule format of week is numerical (week number) and the calculated column  : Project[quality]

Comment: Ok, can you please add a screenshot of your tables (I'd like to see headers and first values)?

Comment: and a data model from PBI where you have links

Comment: @Mik i've done some changes in the model so I can answer other business needs , the data become all in one table and 5% now is a measurment

Comment: Hello Younes, if 5 % is a measure then calculations depens on context, so, please give a measure code.

Comment: here is measure code `Qualité Dev = DIVIDE('public Projet'[temps_VR],[analyse+Dev])*100`

Comment: Hello again,. Does ` Qualité Dev` filters by a week number. What dependents are there.

Comment: hello @MIK :) It depends on date , and from that date we've extracted the week number .

Comment: Hello YOUNES, frankly speaking, the main problem at the moment is that I cant get the point how to extract the value which you want to add (you get with [Qualité Dev] measure). The result you want to achieve seems not that complicated, but there are multiple links and not enough transparent logic. I would like to help you with your DAX,  so if you can give your pbix or dummy pbix, then it's a chance to solve the issue.